# req.body.someElement is undefined when I make POST request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

I have a problem with post request, the error is req.body get undefined values.
I am just started coding, and after researching  on google and stackoverflow an answer, I found some answers on stackoverflow but them dont solve my problem. If I log name it has a value, but if I log req.body.name.type or typeOf name it is undefined. I set my middleware body-parser before I set route but it not working. I also tryed to replace  app.use(bodyParser.json()); with app.use(express.json()); and nothing changed. I atached my code below.

This is my index.js

```
const express = require("express");
require('dotenv').config();
const sequelize = require('./db');
const cors = require('cors');
const router = require("./routes/index");
const errorHandler = require("./middlewares/ErrorHandlingMiddleware");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");


const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use("/api", router);
app.use(errorHandler);


const start = async ()=>{
    try {
        //make connection with our database
        await sequelize.authenticate();
        await sequelize.sync();

        app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, () => {
            let date = new Date(Date.now());
            let serverStartTime = date.getDate() + "." + date.getMonth() + "." + date.getFullYear() + "  " + date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds();
            console.log("Server was start/restart on port 5000: " + serverStartTime);
        });
    } catch (exception){
        console.log(exception);
    }
}

start();
```

This is my routes index

```
const Router = require("express");
const router = new Router();
const brandRouter = require("./brandRouter");
const deviceRouter = require("./deviceRouter");
const typeRouter = require("./typeRouter");
const userRouter = require("./userRouter");

router.use("/user", userRouter);
router.use("/type", typeRouter);
router.use("/brand", brandRouter);
router.use("/device", deviceRouter);

module.exports = router;
```

This is my Router for types

```
const Router = require("express");
const router = new Router();
const typeController = require("../controllers/typeController");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const jsonBodyParser = bodyParser.json();

router.post("/", typeController.addType);
router.get("/", typeController.getAllTypes);

module.exports = router;
```

This is my controller for types

```
const {Type} = require("../models/models");
const ApiError = require("../errors/ApiError");

class TypeController {

    async addType(req, res, next) {
        const {name} = req.body;
        const type = await Type.create({name});
        res.json(req.body);

    }

    async getAllTypes(req, res) {
        const types = await Type.findAll();
        return res.json(types);
    }

}

module.exports = new TypeController();
```

Then method Type.create({name}); is executed it throw error "Cannot read property 'create' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be not with req.body but with this line of code

```
const {Type} = require("../models/models");
```

Error Cannot read property 'create' of undefined is coming because Type is undefined. Check if you are properly importing Type value.